# How to restart docker container automatically after the network interface down/up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have:

```
>uname -a
Linux srv2 6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.7
 Git commit:        baeda1f
 Built:             Tue Oct 25 18:01:58 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.7
  Git commit:       3056208
  Built:            Tue Oct 25 17:59:49 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.10
  GitCommit:        770bd0108c32f3fb5c73ae1264f7e503fe7b2661
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

The Caddy container doesn't want to restart after the network interface cable is reconnected.

I have set `restart: always` for this container.
The problem exists only for an explicitly defined IP in the ports section, such as `- "192.168.1.180:9093:9093"`.
However, for `- "0.0.0.0:9093:9093"`, everything works as intended.

The docker inspect command shows an error:

```
"State": {
    "Status": "exited",
    "Running": false,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": false,
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Dead": false,
    "Pid": 0,
    "ExitCode": 255,
    "Error": "driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint caddy (60eb287b2afa0986217e10fef8def64996f9b387acfb5d050acdac0401914edc): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 192.168.1.180:9093: bind: cannot assign requested address",
    "StartedAt":  "2024-01-08T14:01:12.885988901Z",
    "FinishedAt": "2024-01-30T15:08:13.462577297Z"
},
```

Is there any way to automatically restart such containers using Docker? I mean, I could use a cron job to periodically check the container state, but a Docker solution would be preferable.

Thank you.